# When do uninstall script actually run?

Tags: uninstall

Is it run before it starts to remove managed components ie the first thing after user clicks on Uninstall button, or after everything is removed except Uninstallhandler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_uninstall_handler.htm) hints that the script runs first:

> If the script fails, the uninstall continues but none of the changes performed by the script are committed. Any errors in the script are emailed to the user specified in the Notify on Apex Error field of the package. If no user is specified, the uninstall details will be unavailable.

It wouldn't make sense to uninstall "everything except the uninstall handler", because it could have dependencies on other classes, objects, fields, etc. By necessity, the only reasonable implementation would be to run the script first.